Oustanding medical bills impact on visa
I was in New York last year on holiday and had a small toe fracture, which required me to visit the hospital. My friend gave her phone number to the hospital, and I submitted insurance papers since I was a tourist. However, when the hospital sent a bill of $800 to my friend, she paid it, and I later reimbursed her.
Do you think I should call the hospital to check if there are any unpaid dues? My friend hasn’t received any more bills since then, and it’s been a year. I’m concerned because I don’t want this to create any issues with my B2 visa application. Do unpaid medical bills get reported to immigration?

I do not understand: Why do you think there are unpaid bills? it seems you (via her) paid it, and they have your insurance contact. (Or they just figured out that the outstanding bill will be less then the bureaucracy on getting the money).


Do unpaid medical bills get reported to immigration?

No.
You've done everything right, I don't see a reason for concern.

Just out of curiosity. Doe the unpaid bills get reported to immigration or have an impact on a b2 visa application. I mean if i hadnt cleared the bill.it was b just less than a thousand dollars. They wud have sent the bill or called my friend since she had given her details at the hospital and i submitted my insurance papers. Obviously i filed a claim and got the money later which i wired to my friend

@Sam civil debts are not a concern for immigration and not their problem. If you've done something criminal (e.g.: providing non-existent insurance or paying with a forged check or stolen credit card), then it would be a different matter.

Okay. My insurance company papers were useless i guess coz they didnt do anything except file them ofcourse. They sent the bill to my friend
